# Programmatically access file sharing link - Google Drive, Android

Tags: android, google-drive-api

My application uploads a file into the user's Google Drive (App is authorized with the broadest "Drive" scope).
Now I need to obtain a link to the file I just uploaded.

I'm using Java APIs on Android for uploading the file.
Couldn't find anything in the API reference relating to links.

P.S. Generation of publicly sharable links are preferred.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, the Google Drive Android API does not support sharing (at least as of now). It's a known limitation.

You can use the REST API instead, (e.g. by doing a POST to `https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/{fileId}/permissions` to insert). See [permissions](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/permissions) in the API reference.

The `fileId` value can be obtained by calling `getResourceId()`.

Comment: Oh bummer. I know almost nothing about REST APIs.
Could you point me to some starting point to achieve link sharing?
Thank you for the reply

Comment: Check https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/permissions/update#examples

Comment: @matiash..Thanks for your Answer...But I am getting issue regarding Permission...i have imported google api services...but i am getting issues regarding permission...services.permission..can you help me out..